# web.config to htaccess conversion

Tags: linux, windows, .htaccess, web-config

This both files was in windows server 2008 rc2 iis website.

I migrate this site to Ubuntu Linux, but database pretty urls redirections and some content specific redirections dont work.

windows .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Solo casa
#RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^187\.177\.171\.186$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index\.php [F,L]


# Si no es directorio, y termina con /, eliminarla
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^infochannel.com.mx [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://infochannel.info [L,R=301]

# Anti SPAM internacional validacion-ip
RewriteRule ^validacion-ip$ /util/validacion-ip\.php [NC,L]

# Servicios
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^img\..+$
RewriteRule ^((?!\.png|\.jpg|\.gif).)*$ http\://www\.infochannel\.com\.mx/pagina-no-encontrada [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^agenda/?((?!\.).*)$ /servicios/agenda$1 [NC,L]


RewriteRule ^e([0-9]+)([a-z]+)([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /servicios/quien.aspx\?tipo=personas&id_empresa=$1&id_contacto=$3&letra=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^quien-es-quien/busqueda/?$ /servicios/quien.aspx\?tipo=busqueda [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^quien-es-quien/busqueda/(.*)$ /servicios/quien.aspx\?tipo=busqueda&termino=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^quien-es-quien(/?)$ /servicios/quien.aspx\?letra=a&tipo=personas [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^quien-es-quien/personas/(.*)$ /servicios/quien.aspx\?letra=$1&tipo=personas [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^quien-es-quien/empresas/(.*)$ /servicios/quien.aspx\?letra=$1&tipo=empresas [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^e([0-9]+)-([[:alnum:]]+)/(.*)$ /servicios/directorio.aspx\?id_empresa=$1&letra=$2 [NC,L]
#RewriteRule ^directorio-TI/busqueda/?$ /servicios/directorio.aspx\?tipo=busqueda [NC,L]
#RewriteRule ^directorio-TI/busqueda/(.*)$ /servicios/directorio.aspx\?tipo=busqueda&termino=$1 [NC,L]
#RewriteRule ^directorio-TI/?$ /servicios/directorio.aspx\?letra=a [NC,L]
#RewriteRule ^directorio-TI/(.*)$ /servicios/directorio.aspx\?letra=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^servicios/images/captcha-(.*)\.gif$ /servicios/images/captcha.aspx\?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^images/captcha-(.*)\.gif$ /servicios/images/captcha.aspx\?id=$1 [NC,L]
# RewriteRule ^portada$ /home [R=301,L] OMITI
RewriteRule ^escaparate$ /productos [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^ofertas-tic/([0-9]*)/(.*)$ /servicios/ofertas.aspx\?id_oferta=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^ofertas-tic/?$ /servicios/ofertas.aspx [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^accesorios/votaencuesta\.aspx.*$ /home [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^newsletter/decodifica/(.*)$ /newsletter/editar~$1 [NC,R=301,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^newsletter/desuscribe/(.*)$ /newsletter/eliminar~$1 [NC,R=301,QSA,L]
#RewriteRule ^newsletter/puntodeventa(/?)$ /newsletter/tematico.aspx\?id_seccion=31 [NC,L]
#RewriteRule ^newsletter/raton-(.+)/?$ /newsletter/index-news\.php?fnb=$1 [NC,L]
#RewriteRule ^newsletter/tematico-(.+)/?$ /newsletter/index-tematico\.php?fnb=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^intel_land/?$ /anuncios/2014/Intel/Land_0630_1Red/land.html [NC,L]

#Archivos
RewriteRule ^convocatoria2014/?$ anuncios/2013/Infochannel/Convocatoria-Golf/ConvocatoriaCopaInfochannel.pdf [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^actualiza-tus-datos/?$ landing_page/infochannel/landing_infochannel/landing_infochannel.html [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^distribuidor/?$ /landing_page/infochannel/distribuidor.aspx [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^ensamblador/?$ /landing_page/infochannel/ensamblador.aspx [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^foro/confirmacion/?$ /foro/registrados_new.aspx [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^foro/confirmacion-torneo/?$ /foro/torneo_registrados.aspx [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^integrador-soluciones/?$ /landing_page/infochannel/integrador-soluciones.aspx [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^vive-ingram/?$ /landing_page/viveingram/default.aspx [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^lenovo/?$ /landing_page/lenovo/default.aspx [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^sabrent/?$ /landing_page/sabrent/default.aspx [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^cisco/?$ /landing_page/cisco/default.aspx [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^asistencia/?$ /archivos/asistencia/index.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^kaseya/?$ /landing_page/kaseya/kaseya.aspx [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^aviso-de-privacidad/?$ aviso.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^kaseya-web/?$ /landing_page/kaseya/kaseya-web.aspx [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^intel.htm(\??.*)?$ /landing_page/intel/oct10/default.aspx$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^cgawards\.html$ /landing_page/cgawards/sep10/default.aspx [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^sap/?$ /landing_page/intel/sap/default.aspx [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^d-link(?:/|/(?!\.)(.+))?$ /landing_page/d-link/$1 [NC,L,O]
RewriteRule ^samsung(?:/(.*))?$ /landing_page/samsung/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^emc(?:/(.*))?$ /landing_page/emc/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^polycom(?:/(.*))?$ /landing_page/polycom/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^airos/?$ /landing_page/airos/index\.php [NC,L,O]
RewriteRule ^scansource/((?!\.).*)$ /landing_page/scansource/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^scansource/?$ /landing_page/scansource/ [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^techdata/?((?!\.).*)$ /landing_page/techdata/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^qlikmex/?((?!\.).*)$ /landing_page/qlikmex/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^Nexsys/?((?!\.).*)$ /landing_page/Nexsys/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^Koblenz/?((?!\.).*)$ /landing_page/koblenz/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apolotec_registro/?((?!\.).*)$ /landing_page/apolotec/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^TP-LINK_registro/?((?!\.).*)$ /landing_page/tp-link/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^foro/movil?((?!\.).*)$ /foro/formulario-movil.php$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^registro-cloud/((?!\.).*)$ /landing_page/cloud/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^registro-cloud/?$ /landing_page/cloud/ [NC,L]

# Extras
RewriteRule ^$ /home [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^img/captcha\.jpg$ /util/captcha\.php [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^images/captcha-(.*)\.png$ /util/captcha\.php\?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^img/captcha-(.*)\.png$ /util/captcha\.php\?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)motf~(\d+)x(\d+)~(.*)$ /util/imagen\.php\?ruta=/$1/$4&ancho=$2&alto=$3 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)motfv~(\d+)x(\d+)~(.*)$ /util/imagen-video\.php\?ruta=/$1/$4&ancho=$2&alto=$3 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^js/autorizaciones\.js$ /util/autorizaciones\.php [NC,QSA,L]

# URL's amigables
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index\.php? [NC,QSA,L]
camaras
```

Web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
    <appSettings>
        <add key="com.masterbase.api.index" value="https://api.masterbase.com/soap/users/v3/masterbaseusuarios10.asmx" />
    </appSettings>
    <connectionStrings>
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.net>
        <settings>
            <servicePointManager checkCertificateName="true" checkCertificateRevocationList="false" />
        </settings>
    </system.net>
    <system.web>
        <!--<globalization requestEncoding="ISO-8859-1" responseEncoding="ISO-8859-1" culture="es-MX" />-->
        <!--<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/accesorios/p404.aspx" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" />-->
        <customErrors mode="Off" />
        <compilation debug="true">
            <assemblies>
                <!--<add assembly="MySql.Data, Version=6.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=C5687FC88969C44D"/>-->
                <add assembly="MySql.Data, Version=6.4.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=C5687FC88969C44D" />
                <!-- <add assembly="ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib, Version=0.85.5.452, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1B03E6ACF1164F73"/>-->
                <add assembly="System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
                <add assembly="System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
                <add assembly="System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
                <add assembly="System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
                <add assembly="System.Xml, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
                <add assembly="System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
                <add assembly="System.Web.Services, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
                <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
                <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices.Protocols, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
                <add assembly="System.EnterpriseServices, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
                <add assembly="System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
                <add assembly="System.ServiceProcess, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
                <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
                <add assembly="System.Web.RegularExpressions, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" /></assemblies>
        </compilation>
        <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="20">
        </sessionState>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
        </security>
        <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Script">
            <remove name="PHP53_via_FastCGI" />
        </handlers>
        <rewrite>
          <rules><!-- Redireccionamiento permanente hacia infochannel.info por Hector Hdez. -->
            <rule name="URL1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^tecnologia" ignoreCase="true" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.infochannel.info/taxonomy/term/41" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="URL2" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^channel" ignoreCase="true" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.infochannel.info/taxonomy/term/40" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="URL3" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^vars" ignoreCase="true" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.infochannel.info/taxonomy/term/44" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="URL4" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^ensambladores" ignoreCase="true" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.infochannel.info" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="URL5" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^secciones" ignoreCase="true" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.infochannel.info/taxonomy/term/43" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="URL6" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^tendencias" ignoreCase="true" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.infochannel.info/taxonomy/term/60" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="URL7" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^ventana-global" ignoreCase="true" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.infochannel.info/taxonomy/term/59" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="URL8" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^industria-tic" ignoreCase="true" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.infochannel.info" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="URL9" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^el-raton-enmascarado" ignoreCase="true" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.infochannel.info/taxonomy/term/49" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="URL10" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^seguridad" ignoreCase="true" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.infochannel.info/taxonomy/term/109" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="URL11" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^opinion" ignoreCase="true" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.infochannel.info/taxonomy/term/58" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="URL12" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^reporte-especial" ignoreCase="true" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.infochannel.info/taxonomy/term/1636" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="URL13" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^conectividad" ignoreCase="true" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.infochannel.info/taxonomy/term/55" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="URL14" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^software" ignoreCase="true" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.infochannel.info/taxonomy/term/52" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="URL15" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^cloud" ignoreCase="true" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.infochannel.info/taxonomy/term/53" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="URL16" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^almacenamiento" ignoreCase="true" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.infochannel.info/taxonomy/term/50" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="URL17" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^hardware" ignoreCase="true" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.infochannel.info/taxonomy/term/50" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="URL18" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^punto-de-venta" ignoreCase="true" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.infochannel.info/taxonomy/term/57" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="URL19" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^productos" ignoreCase="true" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.infochannel.info/taxonomy/term/62" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="URL20" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^multimedia" ignoreCase="true" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.infochannel.info/taxonomy/term/47" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="URL21" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^videoentrevistas" ignoreCase="true" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.infochannel.info/taxonomy/term/47" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="URL22" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^galeria" ignoreCase="true" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.infochannel.info/taxonomy/term/48" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="URL23" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^podcast" ignoreCase="true" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.infochannel.info/taxonomy/term/47" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="URL24" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^soluciones" ignoreCase="true" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.infochannel.info" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="URL25" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^tic" ignoreCase="true" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://training.infochannel.info" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="URL26" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^resellers" ignoreCase="true" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.infochannel.info/taxonomy/term/40" />
            </rule>         
            <rule name="URL27" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^mayoristas" ignoreCase="true" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.infochannel.info/taxonomy/term/45" />
            </rule> 
            <rule name="URL28" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^newsletter/suscripcion" ignoreCase="true" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.infochannel.info/registro" />
            </rule> 
            <rule name="URL29" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^servicios/agenda" ignoreCase="true" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.infochannel.info/taxonomy/term/8397" />
            </rule> 
            <rule name="URL30" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^ofertas-tic" ignoreCase="true" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.promochannel.com.mx" />
            </rule> 
            <!--rule name="URL31" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="http://bolsadetrabajo.infochannel.com.mx" ignoreCase="true" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://bolsadetrabajo.infochannel.info" />
            </rule-->
            <!--rule name="URLxx" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^copa2015" ignoreCase="true" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://copa.infochannel.info/" />
            </rule-->
          </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```